# Jquery Select last field having Value greater than Zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all I have  fields like

```
 <div class="dlt_distance_slab">
   <div class="dl_distance_slab">
       <label for="upto"><g:message code="rule.upto.label" default="Upto" /></label>
   </div>
   <div class="dt_distance_slab_show">
        <g:formatNumber number="${ruleInstance?.distanceSlabLimit1}" type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" class="distanceSlablimit"  /> Km
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="dlt_distance_slab">
    <div class="dl_distance_slab">
         <label for="upto"><g:message code="rule.upto.label" default="Upto" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="dt_distance_slab_show">
      <g:formatNumber number="${ruleInstance?.distanceSlabLimit2}" type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" class="distanceSlablimit" /> Km
    </div>      
 </div>
 <div class="dlt_distance_slab">
      <div class="dl_distance_slab">
       <label for="upto"><g:message code="rule.upto.label" default="Upto" /></label>
  </div>
  <div class="dt_distance_slab_show">
       <g:formatNumber number="${ruleInstance?.distanceSlabLimit3}" type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" class="distanceSlablimit" /> Km
  </div>        
</div>
```

i want to select the last formatNumber field having the value  > 0 (all the formatNumber Fiels is having same class ="distanceSlablimit"

How can do it using jquery

Comment: You should include the actual HTML output. What ouput does `<g:formatNumber />` generate?

Comment: Cycle through them with `.each`, if value is greater than 0 save the item in a variable and after the loop you should have the last one stored in your var.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can filter the selected elements [using a function as a parameter for `.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#using-filter-function). Then you can simply use [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).

[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is used to convert the value to a number. Be sure to **always specify the second parameter (radix)**, otherwise you will notice some ["strange" behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description). For example, `'010'` will be translated to the number `8` because in Javascript, a starting zero signals an octal number.

```
$('.distanceSlablimit').filter(function () {
    //replace val() with text() if the elements are not form elements
    return parseInt($(this).val(), 10) > 0;
}).last();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lcpk/3/) / [and another with `.text()`](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lcpk/2/)

Comment: @maaz Added a comment to the code. I have no idea what markup is generated from your (asp? whatever) code. `.val()` is used for form elements (which I have used in my demo if you checked), otherwise you can use `.text()` if those are divs or spans or anything else. Added a second Demo that shows this working.

Comment: @maaz Under your question, there is a comment asking for the actual output. It would have been easier if we have known that, but it should work now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/);

```
$('.distanceSlablimit').filter(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).val() || $(this).text()) > 0); // Checking val() and text() as the type of element is unknown.
}).last();
```

Comment: One unnecessary bracket and unsafe usage of `parseInt`.